# How to stop brute foce attacker on my linux (ubuntu) server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

My ubuntu server is constantly under attack. I installed Fail2Ban as well as disable root login with password and ssh key pair athentication and ufw firewall setup but it did not make any difference.

How to fix this issue?

Here is the log of /var/log/auth.log

```
Sep 8 19:30:02 olas sshd[30871]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=153.36.242.143 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:02 olas sshd[30873]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:04 olas sshd[30875]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=153.36.242.143 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:05 olas sshd[30873]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 7539 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:05 olas sshd[30875]: Failed password for root from 153.36.242.143 port 48063 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:07 olas sshd[30875]: Failed password for root from 153.36.242.143 port 48063 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:07 olas sshd[30873]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 7539 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:08 olas sshd[30875]: Failed password for root from 153.36.242.143 port 48063 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:09 olas sshd[30875]: Received disconnect from 153.36.242.143 port 48063:11: [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:09 olas sshd[30875]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 153.36.242.143 port 48063 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:09 olas sshd[30875]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=153.36.242.143 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:09 olas sshd[30873]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 7539 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:18 olas sshd[30873]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 7539 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:30:18 olas sshd[30873]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 7539 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:18 olas sshd[30873]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 7539: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:18 olas sshd[30873]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:18 olas sshd[30873]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:30:19 olas sudo: revo : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/revo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log
Sep 8 19:30:19 olas sudo: pamunix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by revo(uid=0)
Sep 8 19:30:19 olas sudo: pamunix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 8 19:30:21 olas sshd[30877]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:23 olas sshd[30877]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 28357 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:24 olas sshd[30881]: Invalid user admin4 from 52.163.221.85 port 49400
Sep 8 19:30:24 olas sshd[30881]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:30:24 olas sshd[30881]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=52.163.221.85
Sep 8 19:30:25 olas sshd[30877]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 28357 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:26 olas sshd[30881]: Failed password for invalid user admin4 from 52.163.221.85 port 49400 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:26 olas sshd[30881]: Received disconnect from 52.163.221.85 port 49400:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:26 olas sshd[30881]: Disconnected from invalid user admin4 52.163.221.85 port 49400 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:28 olas sshd[30877]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 28357 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:36 olas sshd[30877]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 28357 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:30:36 olas sshd[30877]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 28357 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:36 olas sshd[30877]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 28357: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:36 olas sshd[30877]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:36 olas sshd[30877]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:30:39 olas sshd[30883]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:40 olas sshd[30883]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49564 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:43 olas sshd[30883]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49564 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:45 olas sshd[30885]: Invalid user ftpuser from 157.230.208.92 port 51008
Sep 8 19:30:45 olas sshd[30885]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:30:45 olas sshd[30885]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.230.208.92
Sep 8 19:30:46 olas sshd[30883]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49564 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:47 olas sshd[30885]: Failed password for invalid user ftpuser from 157.230.208.92 port 51008 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:47 olas sshd[30885]: Received disconnect from 157.230.208.92 port 51008:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:47 olas sshd[30885]: Disconnected from invalid user ftpuser 157.230.208.92 port 51008 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:48 olas sshd[30883]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49564 ssh2
Sep 8 19:30:54 olas sshd[30883]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49564 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:30:54 olas sshd[30883]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49564 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:54 olas sshd[30883]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 49564: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:30:54 olas sshd[30883]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:54 olas sshd[30883]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:30:56 olas sshd[30887]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:30:59 olas sshd[30887]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:00 olas sshd[30889]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=183.212.176.50 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:01 olas sshd[30887]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:02 olas sshd[30889]: Failed password for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:03 olas sshd[30887]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:05 olas sshd[30889]: Failed password for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:05 olas sshd[30887]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:06 olas sshd[30889]: Failed password for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:08 olas sshd[30887]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:08 olas sshd[30889]: Failed password for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:10 olas sshd[30889]: Failed password for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:10 olas sshd[30887]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:10 olas sshd[30887]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6329 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:10 olas sshd[30887]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 6329: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:10 olas sshd[30887]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:10 olas sshd[30887]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:31:11 olas sshd[30889]: Failed password for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:11 olas sshd[30889]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 183.212.176.50 port 21090 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:11 olas sshd[30889]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 183.212.176.50 port 21090: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:11 olas sshd[30889]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=183.212.176.50 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:11 olas sshd[30889]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:31:14 olas sshd[30891]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:16 olas sshd[30891]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26292 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:29 olas sshd[30891]: message repeated 5 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26292 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:31:29 olas sshd[30891]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26292 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:29 olas sshd[30891]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 26292: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:29 olas sshd[30891]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:29 olas sshd[30891]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:31:32 olas sshd[30893]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:34 olas sshd[30893]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49179 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:48 olas sshd[30893]: message repeated 5 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49179 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:31:48 olas sshd[30893]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 49179 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:48 olas sshd[30893]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 49179: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:48 olas sshd[30893]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:48 olas sshd[30893]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:31:50 olas sshd[30895]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:31:53 olas sshd[30895]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6144 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:54 olas sshd[30897]: Invalid user test from 134.209.187.43 port 55388
Sep 8 19:31:54 olas sshd[30897]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:31:54 olas sshd[30897]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=134.209.187.43
Sep 8 19:31:55 olas sshd[30895]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6144 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:56 olas sshd[30897]: Failed password for invalid user test from 134.209.187.43 port 55388 ssh2
Sep 8 19:31:56 olas sshd[30897]: Received disconnect from 134.209.187.43 port 55388:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:56 olas sshd[30897]: Disconnected from invalid user test 134.209.187.43 port 55388 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:31:57 olas sshd[30895]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6144 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:02 olas sshd[30895]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6144 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:32:03 olas sshd[30901]: Invalid user ftpadmin from 142.93.155.194 port 56054
Sep 8 19:32:03 olas sshd[30901]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:03 olas sshd[30901]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=142.93.155.194
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30895]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6144 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30895]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 6144 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30895]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 6144: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30895]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30895]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30901]: Failed password for invalid user ftpadmin from 142.93.155.194 port 56054 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30901]: Received disconnect from 142.93.155.194 port 56054:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:05 olas sshd[30901]: Disconnected from invalid user ftpadmin 142.93.155.194 port 56054 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:08 olas sshd[30903]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:08 olas sshd[30899]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.92.16.94 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:09 olas sshd[30903]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26908 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:10 olas sshd[30899]: Failed password for root from 220.92.16.94 port 56924 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:10 olas sshd[30899]: Received disconnect from 220.92.16.94 port 56924:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:10 olas sshd[30899]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 220.92.16.94 port 56924 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:10 olas sshd[30905]: Invalid user p@$$wOrd from 52.230.68.68 port 41692
Sep 8 19:32:10 olas sshd[30905]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:10 olas sshd[30905]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=52.230.68.68
Sep 8 19:32:12 olas sshd[30903]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26908 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:12 olas sshd[30905]: Failed password for invalid user p@$$wOrd from 52.230.68.68 port 41692 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:12 olas sshd[30905]: Received disconnect from 52.230.68.68 port 41692:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:12 olas sshd[30905]: Disconnected from invalid user p@$$wOrd 52.230.68.68 port 41692 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:14 olas sshd[30903]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26908 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30903]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26908 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30903]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 26908 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30903]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 26908: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30903]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30903]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30908]: Invalid user student2 from 178.128.104.246 port 64683
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30908]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:23 olas sshd[30908]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=178.128.104.246
Sep 8 19:32:24 olas sshd[30908]: Failed password for invalid user student2 from 178.128.104.246 port 64683 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:24 olas sshd[30908]: Received disconnect from 178.128.104.246 port 64683:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:24 olas sshd[30908]: Disconnected from invalid user student2 178.128.104.246 port 64683 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:25 olas sshd[30907]: Invalid user vbox from 111.231.202.61 port 33124
Sep 8 19:32:25 olas sshd[30907]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:25 olas sshd[30907]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=111.231.202.61
Sep 8 19:32:25 olas sshd[30913]: Invalid user ts3 from 159.65.140.148 port 51662
Sep 8 19:32:25 olas sshd[30913]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:25 olas sshd[30913]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=159.65.140.148
Sep 8 19:32:26 olas sshd[30911]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:27 olas sshd[30907]: Failed password for invalid user vbox from 111.231.202.61 port 33124 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:27 olas sshd[30913]: Failed password for invalid user ts3 from 159.65.140.148 port 51662 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:27 olas sshd[30913]: Received disconnect from 159.65.140.148 port 51662:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:27 olas sshd[30913]: Disconnected from invalid user ts3 159.65.140.148 port 51662 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:28 olas sshd[30911]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 47503 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:29 olas sshd[30907]: Received disconnect from 111.231.202.61 port 33124:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:29 olas sshd[30907]: Disconnected from invalid user vbox 111.231.202.61 port 33124 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:31 olas sshd[30911]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 47503 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:39 olas sshd[30911]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 47503 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:32:40 olas sshd[30915]: Invalid user admin from 45.55.47.149 port 60875
Sep 8 19:32:40 olas sshd[30915]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:40 olas sshd[30915]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=45.55.47.149
Sep 8 19:32:41 olas sshd[30911]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 47503 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:41 olas sshd[30911]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 47503 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:41 olas sshd[30911]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 47503: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:41 olas sshd[30911]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:41 olas sshd[30911]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:32:42 olas sshd[30917]: Invalid user xbmc from 157.230.174.111 port 39560
Sep 8 19:32:42 olas sshd[30917]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:42 olas sshd[30917]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.230.174.111
Sep 8 19:32:42 olas sshd[30915]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 45.55.47.149 port 60875 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:42 olas sshd[30915]: Received disconnect from 45.55.47.149 port 60875:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:42 olas sshd[30915]: Disconnected from invalid user admin 45.55.47.149 port 60875 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:43 olas sshd[30917]: Failed password for invalid user xbmc from 157.230.174.111 port 39560 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:43 olas sshd[30917]: Received disconnect from 157.230.174.111 port 39560:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:43 olas sshd[30917]: Disconnected from invalid user xbmc 157.230.174.111 port 39560 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:44 olas sshd[30919]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:32:46 olas sshd[30919]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 4441 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:54 olas sshd[30919]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 4441 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:32:56 olas sshd[30921]: Invalid user p@55wOrd from 75.87.52.203 port 33004
Sep 8 19:32:56 olas sshd[30921]: pamunix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 8 19:32:56 olas sshd[30921]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.87.52.203
Sep 8 19:32:57 olas sshd[30919]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 4441 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:58 olas sshd[30921]: Failed password for invalid user p@55wOrd from 75.87.52.203 port 33004 ssh2
Sep 8 19:32:58 olas sshd[30921]: Received disconnect from 75.87.52.203 port 33004:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Sep 8 19:32:58 olas sshd[30921]: Disconnected from invalid user p@55wOrd 75.87.52.203 port 33004 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:33:00 olas sshd[30919]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 4441 ssh2
Sep 8 19:33:00 olas sshd[30919]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 112.85.42.178 port 4441 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 8 19:33:00 olas sshd[30919]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.85.42.178 port 4441: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 8 19:33:00 olas sshd[30919]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:33:00 olas sshd[30919]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Sep 8 19:33:02 olas sshd[30923]: pamunix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=112.85.42.178 user=root
Sep 8 19:33:05 olas sshd[30923]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 27863 ssh2
Sep 8 19:33:15 olas sshd[30923]: message repeated 4 times: [ Failed password for root from 112.85.42.178 port 27863 ssh2]
Sep 8 19:33:15 olas sudo: revo : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/revo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /var/log/auth.log
Sep 8 19:33:15 olas sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by revo(uid=0)
```

Comment: Well obviously your `ufw` and fail2ban setup is not working… you should show some more details about how you configured them.

Comment: Use `knockd` to open/close your `SSH` port. This will reduce the number of hacking attempts tremendously.

Comment: (skhck is right, your fail2ban setup is broken) Rather then knockd, set up VPNs and limit ssh access to the LAN and across the VPN - way more robust and extensible then knocks, for not-a-lot-more-work.

Comment: Fail2Ban is installed with default configurations.

Comment: you should deny access to root logins as well. Login as non-admin and `su` or `sudo` to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99% of the brute force attacks are just script kiddies, they are not even editing the scripts. They look for port 22, if they get a connection they run the brute force login script. For those just move your ssh port to a new port "2200, 2220". As much as security through obscurity is not something I usually recommend for this it works.

Then fix your fail2ban for the new port, and either setup knockd like @dirdi suggested or use a VPN like @davidgo suggested. Which way you go just depends on the level of security you need/desire. You can even do both.

Security is not a install this and be done type issue. Security is about layers of protection not just one app.

Comment: FYI - you have to port forward the knockd port to your server as well.